# How to get parent element of a deep child?

Tags: javascript, html

I have an HTML like -

```
<main>
<section>
  <div class="parent">
    <div class='level_1'>
      <div class='level_2'>
        <div class='level_3'>
          <span class='click_here'></span>
        </div><!--level 3-->
      </div><!--level 2-->
    </div> <!--level 1-->
  </div> <!--parent-->
<section>

<section>
  <!-- same as given above -->
<section>
<main>
```

See there is a span element of class `click_here`. So If user clicks to this span element I want to grab its grand parent element with having class `parent` by Javascript.
I know the basic solution like accessing `e.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement` but this is not good because the clicked item might be in more deep level than given in example.
Is their any other solution by using Javascript ?

Comment: [closest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest)

Answer (score 2):

You could do `e.target.closest('.parent')` which lets you select the closest parent with whatever selector you're looking for.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `mouseEvent.target.closest('.parent');` to fetch the closest `.parent` element of the clicked element and this will work for any arbitrary nesting level. Example:

```js
let span = document.querySelector('span');

span.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
 console.log(e.target.closest('.parent'));
});
```

```css
span {
 display: block;
 width: 100px;
 height: 100px;
 background: tomato;
}
```

```html
<main>
<section>
  <div class="parent">
    <div class='level_1'>
      <div class='level_2'>
        <div class='level_3'>
          <span class='click_here'></span>
        </div><!--level 3-->
      </div><!--level 2-->
    </div> <!--level 1-->
  </div> <!--parent-->
<section>

<section>
  <!-- same as given above -->
<section>
<main>
```